# Is tag35=4 sent via ToApp or ToAdmin

Tags: c#, quickfix, fix-protocol

I want to stop all duplicate messages(orders really) but allow message
tag 35=4 through. This is needed after a reconnect it seems.

```
8=FIX.4.2^A9=100^A35=4^A34=335^A43=Y^A49=YYYYYYYYY^A52=20150218-05:16:21.353^A56=IBXXXX^A122=20150218-05:16:21.352^A36=337^A123=Y^A10=116^A
```

Is this message sent via ToApp or ToAdmin? I need to know where to put
the logic...

Comment: What?  Your question has little to no context.  What do you mean by sent via ToApp or ToAdmin?

Comment: The question makes sense within the context of QuickFIX, which allows an application to use `ToApp` and `ToAdmin` to add custom logic to handle outbound application messages and administrative messages, respectively.

Comment: Use this as a reference http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/latestEP/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an administrative message, so it will be sent via `ToAdmin`.

Comment: Is there a list that defines which is which somewhere? It would be useful to know.

Comment: Check out [FIXimate](http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/), and select whichever version of FIX you are using. The left side of the page lists Application Level (`ToApp`/`FromApp`) and Session Layer (`ToAdmin`/`FromAdmin`) messages.